# Изменения ключа в json файле с помощью php

Tags: php, json

Я пытаюсь поменять в json файле поменять `TVOFFicial1` на `GameOver`, но у меня файл всё время становится пустым иль вообще не меняется.

Код:

```php
$NEW_WORLD = file_get_contents("accounts/".$_COOKIE['accname'].".json");
$iNEW_WORLD = json_decode($NEW_WORLD, true);
$iNEW_WORLD = str_replace($_COOKIE['accname'], $_POST['homes'],$iNEW_WORLD);
$NEW_WORLD = json_decode($iNEW_WORLD);
file_put_contents("accounts/".$_COOKIE['accname'].".json", $NEW_WORLD);
```

json:

```
{"TVOFFicial1":{"Name":"TVOFFicial1","Avatar":"BeconAvatar.png","Description":"","Password":"5c28c7f51296e7b129220d40118cb46d","Ban":false,"Role":"member"}}
```

Меняться вообще должно `{"TVOFFicial1":{"Name":"TVOFFicial1",`

Answer (score 0):

Вы перед записью в файл делаете `json_decode`, а нужно `json_encode`

Также `str_replace` вы применяете на **массиве**, а **надо на строке.** Вы не определились с типом данных для работы?

Нужно **либо** перевести в массив и работать с массивом, а потом декодировать обратно в `json`, **либо** работать сразу со строкой и тогда никакие `decode`, `encode` вообще не нужны.

Также, чтобы отслеживать процесс на каждом этапе, на каждой строчке выполнения, можно (и нужно) использовать **[отладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**. Тогда сможете видеть что происходит без гадания на кофейной гуще.